# Python-docx and ElemetTree: how to find where hyperlinks lie within a paragraph

Tags: elementtree, python-docx

I'm using python-docx and ElementTree to convert Word documents to XML, and it's working well except for hyperlinks.

I'm able to find which python-docx paragraphs have a hyperlink, however if the hyperlink is in the middle of the paragraph text, I don't know where to render the hyperlink when writing the output to XML.

Is there a way to iterate through all elements in a paragraph?
If I understand correctly, iterating through the runs will only consider the `<w:r>` elements, so I expect my hyperlink element will be in between 2 of the runs. How can I figure out which two?

Answer (score 2):

`python-docx` uses `lxml` for working on its underlying XML. I expect you'll do much better if you stick to that rather than introducing Python's `xml.etree.ElementTree`, if that's what you mean by `ElementTree`.

For a paragraph, you can generate the underlying XML string by calling:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    print(paragraph._p.xml)
```

All of the other `lxml.etree._Element` methods are also available to you, as well as a `python-docx` overloaded `.xpath()` method that lets you write expressions with namespace prefixes instead of the whole namespace URL, like `paragraph._p.xpath("w:rPr")`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at lxml.

Comment: are you saying that I don't need an ElementTree type approach, but should be able to just iterate through the paragraphs and write `paragraph._p.xml` straight to the output file?
Sorry I'm not a SE, and am sure I'm missing the trivial way to do this task.

Comment: You'll have to decide whether it is enough for your application or not, but there is no need to make XML manipulation-level calls to inspect the XML text for a paragraph. For example you could do a `str` level search for the target element with: `[p for p in document.paragraphs if "w:rPr" in p._p.xml]`. If you _did_ need to manipulate the XML directly, what I'm saying is you should do it with `lxml`, using `python-docx` to get _close_ to the element you need and making e.g. `paragraph._p.xpath("w:rPr") calls from there, rather than unzipping the whole package and navigating from the top.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I don't need to manipulate anything, just want to directly convert a docx file to XML. The person who started this work thought the ElementTree approach was necessary to be able to render the images and tables.

Comment: print(paragraph._p.xml) prints out the xml of the entire word doc. Is it possible to get the xml of just the individual paragraphs? I suppose you could break the xml by different paragraphs, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm a bit late but maybe someone will find that answer useful.
Let's say you have a paragraph in a MS Word document that has a hyperlink inside it, like this:

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. **https://www.google.com/** The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.

You can check how it looks like in xml when you 1) change the extension of your .docx file to .docx.zip or 2) by printing the xml => print(paragraph._p.xml)
!)When you look at the document.xml file, you will see something like this:

```
<w:hyperlink w:history="1" r:id="rId9">
  <w:r w:rsidR="000D6596" w:rsidRPr="00302570">
   <w:rPr>
    <w:rStyle w:val="Hipercze"/>
    <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
    <w:spacing w:val="-4"/>
   </w:rPr>
  <w:t>https/google.com</w:t>
 </w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
```

Then you could find the relationship ids of all the hyperlinks that you have in your document (if you have more than one hyperlink, you probably want to save the rIds to a list):

```
import docx 
from docx.oxml.ns import qn


for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        hyperlink = paragraph._p.xpath("./w:hyperlink")
        if len(hyperlink) > 0:
            hyperlink = hyperlink[0]
            hyperlink_rel_id = hyperlink.get(qn("r:id"))
```

Once you have the rId you can get to that link, delete, modify, etc. Another way to get the rIds here:

```
        from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT


        link_text = 'https://www.google.pl/'
        document = docx.Document(path)
        rels = document.part.rels
        for rel in rels:
            if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
                if rels[rel]._target == link_text:
                  # if the text of the link is the same as the one you are looking for 
                  # do something
```